# django admin filters and mongodb: Caught DatabaseError while rendering: This query is not supported by the database

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, filter, django-admin

Using django non-rel 1.3 with MongoDB as the DB backend:

I'm trying to setting a filter on a field (CharField) of MyModel class, in the corresponding django ModelAdmin class, like this:

`class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('myfield',)`

but what i get is:

`TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/myapp/mymodel`

`Caught DatabaseError while rendering: This query is not supported by the database.`

It seems that Django MongoDB engine doesn't support filter, but i don't find documentation about.

EDIT:
The error comes from template file .../admin/templates/change_list.html, and the line that throws it is line 85:

`{% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}{% admin_list_filter cl spec %}{% endfor %}`

My model is:

`class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield=models.CharField(max_length='300')`

and my admin model is:

`class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('myfield',)`

and register it with:

`admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)`
.

Debugging the code, the exception is throwed by method `check_query` of basecompiler.py. This method verifies that `self.query.distinct or self.query.extra or self.query.having` is true and then throws the exception (self.query.distinct is equal to 'True' in the interested query object, so the cause is this).

Comment: No idea why this is being voted down. I'm having the exact same issue, and thinking there shouldn't be a join required to filter by a CharField...

Comment: I have edited the question adding it the problematic loc

Comment: Please show your models code and the complete admin definition for that model.

Comment: Edited the question, now it includes model and ModelAdmin definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because Django Admin's list_filters use a `distinct()` when trying to figure out which members belong in the list.

Our (internal, hacky) solution was to patch django non_rel to make the distinct call happen in memory rather then on the DB end.  This is by no means the 'correct' solution, and we haven't made a point of testing it in use cases other then ours, but it's better than nothing.

YMMV.

https://github.com/BlueDragonX/django-nonrel/commit/4025327efbe5c17c6b77e0497c2b433819c42918

Comment: Why does it make the distinct call in memory rather than on the DB? PS: thanks for the commit

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Python/Django newb, but I managed to fix this by copying AllValuesFieldListFilter from https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/admin/filters.py (make sure to change your branch to your version of Django) and then I removed the call to `distinct`. Had to import a bunch of stuff. Then it works. I also applied the changes from @AlexeyMK's answer to make it distinct again.

for 1.4:

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import FieldListFilter
from django.contrib.admin.util import (get_model_from_relation, reverse_field_path, get_limit_choices_to_from_path, prepare_lookup_value)
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode, force_unicode

class MongoFieldListFilter(FieldListFilter):
def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
    self.lookup_kwarg = field_path
    self.lookup_kwarg_isnull = '%s__isnull' % field_path
    self.lookup_val = request.GET.get(self.lookup_kwarg, None)
    self.lookup_val_isnull = request.GET.get(self.lookup_kwarg_isnull,
                                             None)
    parent_model, reverse_path = reverse_field_path(model, field_path)
    queryset = parent_model._default_manager.all()
    # optional feature: limit choices base on existing relationships
    # queryset = queryset.complex_filter(
    #    {'%s__isnull' % reverse_path: False})
    limit_choices_to = get_limit_choices_to_from_path(model, field_path)
    queryset = queryset.filter(limit_choices_to)

    def uniquify(coll):  # enforce uniqueness, preserve order
      seen = set()
      return [x for x in coll if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

    self.lookup_choices = uniquify(queryset.order_by(field.name).values_list(field.name, flat=True))

    super(MongoFieldListFilter, self).__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)

def expected_parameters(self):
    return [self.lookup_kwarg, self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]

def choices(self, cl):
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE
    yield {
        'selected': (self.lookup_val is None
            and self.lookup_val_isnull is None),
        'query_string': cl.get_query_string({},
            [self.lookup_kwarg, self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
        'display': _('All'),
    }
    include_none = False
    for val in self.lookup_choices:
        if val is None:
            include_none = True
            continue
        val = smart_unicode(val)
        yield {
            'selected': self.lookup_val == val,
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                self.lookup_kwarg: val,
            }, [self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
            'display': val,
        }
    if include_none:
        yield {
            'selected': bool(self.lookup_val_isnull),
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                self.lookup_kwarg_isnull: 'True',
            }, [self.lookup_kwarg]),
            'display': EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE,
        }
```

Then specify it to use this filter like so:

```
list_filter = (('myfield', MongoFieldListFilter),)
```

It's nice because there's no patching required.

Answer (score 0):

The query that the admin filters require isn't supported by Mongo-Db-Engine, as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-non-relational/yneQ6kbAM2g)

Answer (score -1):

So basically you want to Retrieve only some fields from mongo isn't it?

Looking at the [tutorial](http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html#adding-some-templates), I believe you'll have to this in the Django View or Template

You can also try the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/django-non-relational) for further info

Comment: No, i want to create django admin filters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: You'll need to use the nosql django fork to be compatible with mongodb . (Django MongoDB Engine uses a forked version of Django 1.3 that adds non-relational support.)

Comment: i have uninstalled django and installed django-nonrel, but nothing changes :(

Answer (score -1):

What type is `myfield` of? You can't order by relationships.