# Django MongoDB DatabaseError at /admin

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to switch over to using MongoDB with Django, but have run into an issue.  Namely, some parts of the site give a 'DatabaseError at /admin/myApp/myModel: This query is not supported by the database.'  As described by the similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138816/django-admin-filters-and-mongodb-caught-databaseerror-while-rendering-this-que/13193947#13193947), this error arrises from .../admin/templates/change_list.html, and the line that throws it is line 85:

```
{% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}{% admin_list_filter cl spec %}{% endfor %}
```

I have several models, containing a variety of CharFields, IntegerFields, BooleanFields, DateFields, URLFields, and DecimalFields.  There is also a ManyToManyField:

```
class Trail(models.Model):
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(TrailSection)
```

I have had no problems with users, etc, but whenever I try to access the Trail model, I get the above error.  There are no problems when I click on the TrailSection part of the /admin page, but this error appears when I click on Trail.  It is ok to call

```
associatedTrails = Trail.objects.filter(sections=sect).order_by('-date').values('trail_id','name')
```

but I get the error when I later use

```
for t in associatedTrails:
```

The other question on StackOverflow documents this error as a bug that needs to be fixed, but my question is this: Why does this only happen sometimes?  Why is there no problem with TrailSections or other /admin pages, but this one throws an error?  Is there a good way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out django-norel does not support ManyToManyFields.  They can be, for the most part, replaced by ListFields, which are supported in norel but not relational databases.  More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300218/django-nonrel-form-field-for-listfield).

In addition to ManyToManyFields not being supported, list_filter in admin.py can contain only one item.  Maybe someone else can comment as to why, but removing using a single filter got rid of the error for all models.